# How to build a nested params hash with a custom route in Ruby-on-Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a route that looks like this:

`get ':q', to: 'foo#bar'`

and I can access it inside my foo_controller through:

`params[:q]`.

Is it somehow possible to nest the params-hash so that it can access it through:

`params[:namespace][:q]`

Comment: The structure of the params hash has nothing to do with the routes. Rather it just depends on what query string or request body was sent by the client (which boils down to the link/form). What `get :q` does is creates a route that matches the path `/q`.

Comment: You nest inputs by naming them `[foo][bar]baz` which Rack then deserializes into nested hashes. You can achieve this with [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.4/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) but you should really get a grasp of the fundamentals first.

Answer (score 1):

yes, its possible and very easy to do so.
1. Declare the routes properly for the nested resources. refer to the link1 below.

2. allow nested attributes in the strong parameters. like this:

   `params.require(:abc).permit(:name, :email, custome_attribute: { :id, :_delete, :name})`

Remember :id and :_delete is neceesary if you want to delete the nested resources. Now construct your form using rails form builder. follow the 2nd link below.

Please go through the following tutorial:

> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources
>
> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms